# awk to convert scientific notation in file to original integer in csv file

Tags: awk

I am trying to use `awk` to covert all scientific notation to its original integer. The below does execute, but the scientific notation remains in the output.

**awk**

```
awk -F, '{
for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i+0 == $i && $i ~ /e/) $i = sprintf("%.0f", $i)
} 1' f.csv
```

**f.csv**

```
[Header],,
....
....
,,
[Data],,
ID,Number,Test
1,2.07E-11,a
2,2.07E-11,a
```

**desired**

```
[Header],,
....
....
,,
[Data],,
ID,Number,Test
1,207081000000,a
2,207081000000,a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few issues with the current code and/or description:

- trying to match `E` against `e` will always fail
- input of `2.07E-11` becomes `0.000000000207` (not `207081000000`) and with a format of `%.0f` this would display as `0`
- even if the input is `2.07E+11` this should convert to `207000000000` and *not* `207081000000` (ie, where did the `81` come from? or is this a typo?)
- output field delimiter has not been defined
- why loop through all fields if only the 2nd field is of interest?

Modifying the input file:

```
$ cat f.csv
[Header],,
....
....
,,
[Data],,
ID,Number,Test
1,2.07E-11,a
2,2.07E+11,a
```

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","}
      { if ($2+0 == $2 && $2 ~ /[eE]/)
           $2=sprintf("%.0f",$2)
      }
1' f.csv
```

This generates:

```
[Header],,
....
....
,,
[Data],,
ID,0,Test
1,0,a
2,207000000000,a
```

---

Assuming the input may contain scientific values in different fields we can push our changes into OP's code ...

```
$ cat f.csv
[Header],,
....
....
,,
[Data],,
ID,Number,Test
1,2.07E-11,a
2,2.07E+11,a
3,skip_this_field,5.6789E+11
```

Updating OP's `awk` code:

```
awk '
BEGIN { FS=OFS=","}
      { for (i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            if ($i+0 == $i && $i ~ /[eE]/)
               $i=sprintf("%.0f",$i)
      }
1' f.csv
```

This generates:

```
[Header],,
....
....
,,
[Data],,
ID,Number,Test
1,0,a
2,207000000000,a
3,skip_this_field,567890000000
```

Comment: In the final output all lines should be converted but only 1 line seems to be. I think maybe the input may have something wrong. Thank you :)

Comment: @justaguy we would need to see the question updated with a (small) sample file that demonstrates the issue (only 1 line converted)

Comment: It was the input file.... the script works perfect. Thank you :).